# Not able to save data into Plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

HI i have a `NSMutableDictionary` and i added 5 objects with keys (latitude, longitude, intensity, image, metaimage) then I tried to add it into a `NSMutableArray` and write that `NSMutableArray` to a .plist file. But Actually it is not writing. My .plist file is still empty.

Please check my code:

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"history.plist"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

if([latitude length]>0 && [longitude length]>0){
[dictValue setObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
[dictValue setObject:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
}
[dictValue setObject:metaImage forKey:@"imageData"];
[dictValue setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
if([_intensity.text length]>0){
[dictValue setObject:_intensity.text forKey:@"intensity"];
}else{
    intensityAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Beta App" message:@"Please select intensity." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [intensityAlert show];
}

if(fileExists){
    finalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [finalArray addObject:dictValue];
    NSLog(@"dd%@",dictValue);

}else{
    [finalArray addObject:dictValue];
    NSLog(@"new%@",finalArray);

}
[finalArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

after that  i use following code to check the data inside plist

```
   finalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"server%@",finalArray);
```

It printing nil value.

Comment: What data type is `metaImage` and `image`? You can't store `UIImage` objects in a plist without first converting them to `NSData`.

Comment: uiimage,so i need to convert that to nsdata ryt?

Comment: If by "ryt" you mean "right", then yes, you need to convert the `UIImage` to `NSData` and put the `NSData` into the dictionary.

Comment: like this  imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0);

Comment: Or use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. Either works depending on the images.

Comment: but why its replacing existing value???  it always working in this part  }else{
    [finalArray addObject:dictValue];
    NSLog(@"new%@",finalArray);

}

Comment: Probably because the file is never being written because you are trying to store non-plist values in the array. Check the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:`. If it returns `NO` it means the file wasn't saved. You can only have plist compatible values within the array.

Comment: UIImage to NSData conversion taking lots of time,is there any way to reduce that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

1. finalArray is allocated in else:

   ```
   if(fileExists){
    finalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [finalArray addObject:dictValue];
    NSLog(@"dd%@",dictValue);
   }else{
    // let be sure that final array allocated : [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWith...]
    [finalArray addObject:dictValue];
    NSLog(@"new%@",finalArray);
   }
   ```
2. metaImage or image must be saved by NSData format

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As Document for `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag`:

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are
>   property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber,
>   NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and
>   returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the
>   resultant file would not be a valid property list.

You can try save image into a folder , and save the image relative file path to plist file.